# How do I use the "getopt" function in PHP for CLI argument parsing?

Tags: php

I'm trying to read the "fancy" arguments to a PHP CLI script started with:

```
php test.php meow quack --this-is-a-test="any text goes here lalala" woof
```

In PHP; I want this to become an array like:

```
[
    'meow' =>               null,
    'quack' =>              null,
    '--this-is-a-test' =>   'any text goes here lalala',
    'woof' =>               null
]
```

(It's not strictly necessary that the "valueless" arguments get assigned "null", but that's what seems to make the most sense to me.)

I've found the very promising function "getopt" ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php ) but even after reading that page like ten times, I'm unable to work out how it's meant to be used. The examples make no sense to me. It appears to require me to specify the format?

I don't think I've ever been *this* confused about any PHP function, actually. Usually, I have some vague idea of how it's supposed to be used, but this time, it's like reading an alien language!

PS: It should also be noted that I have found a library for doing this, but I don't like to rely on "third-party" code, especially not when PHP has a function for it and it's something this "basic" or "close to the core", so to speak.

Comment: Why do not you stick to `$argv` and `$argc` variables ? You can then use `strpos` to find the first `=` sign and then use `substr` to get the name and value of the CLI argument.

Comment: @IVOGELOV That was my first thought, but it soon proved way too complex to attempt to account for the OS-varying quotes, rules for escaped quotes, different forms of flags/arguments/options/whatever (the terminology seems very muddled)...

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($argv)` on your example command-line ? It seems quite straight-forward to me, even when you include escaped quotes. And why would you want to support all the various forms of flags/arguments/options ? Why do not you choose some simple scheme (e.g. all options begin with 2 dashes and those who require an argument use "=" to supply it) and stick with it ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Um... Yes, I "have tried" that. I know what format $argv has. The problems are, as I already said, about parsing their values. It's not simple or straight-forward and changes between OSes...

Comment: Well then, if the PHP manual does not seem to provide what you are looking for - perhaps you can look at some existing code, like in https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/getopt/php-getopt-function-examples.html